# Orchestrate execution of several Jenkinsfile using only declarative syntax

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to, from a Jenkinsfile, orchestrate the execution of another Jenkinsfile using **for all of them declarative syntax**?

I mean, I would like to have a Jenkinsfile like this one (to which I refer as the 'orchestrator'):

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Invoke another Jenkinsfile') {
            ... code here to invoke folder1/Jenkinsfile ...
        }
    }
}
```

The `folder1/Jenkinsfile` will be a regular Jenkinsfile like this one:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you might have guessed, the file structure of this example will be:

```
folder1
│   └── Jenkinsfile
└── Jenkinfile //this will be the 'orchestrator'
```

How can I achieve this? Could you help me figuring out the code that should contain the orchestrator to invoke the other Jenkinsfile?

I expect a serial & sync process in which the orchestrator waits till the `folder1/Jenkinsfile` execution is finished to mark the step 'Invoke another Jenkinsfile' as green and then proceed with the remaining steps.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use the `build` step to invoke other pipelines, but AFAIK you cannot directly call other jenkinsfiles that consist of whole pipelines (part of pipelines would be possible, see answer). You have to create jobs for the other jenkinsfiles and refer to them by name from the `build` step.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried to load an actual ".jenkinsfile" but I have made that with groovy scripts, which is what a jenkinsfile is in the end. I have made so like this:

```
   def outsider = load "outsider.groovy"
```

As can be seen here: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/

Comment: That's not possible with declarative syntax pipelines as it gives you the following error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one pipeline { ... } block can be executed in a single run.